# Definir tempo limite de execução como infinito pode afetar a performance do servidor?

Tags: php, desempenho, script

Geralmente, vejo muitas pessoas (inclusive eu já tive) problemas com tempo de execução de um script em PHP. Isso porque, por padrão, o PHP define um tempo limite para execução de um script em 30 segundos.

Esses problemas ocorrem geralmente quando o PHP está trabalhando em cima de uma requisição demorada. Aí a solução que é adotada geralmente é aumentar o tempo limite de execução do script.

Porém, já vi alguns casos onde o programador adotou como solução definir `0` para o tempo limite de execução do script (e `0` no PHP significa sem limites) já que o tempo de espera poderia variar (por exemplo, caso o script esteja esperando por uma requisição externa).

A minha dúvida é: Se eu definir o tempo limite como `0` para tornar esse tempo de espera infinito, poderia ocasionar perda de performance no meu servidor?

Por exemplo, se eu tiver vários scripts rodando e esperando em média 1 minuto, devido a um processamento ser demorado (seja consulta ao banco, leitura de arquivos etc), isso pode causar algum prejuízo a minha aplicação em termos de performance?

É realmente seguro usar `set_time_limit(0)` (ou qualquer outra forma que existir de definir um tempo espera para execução completa de um script como infinita)?

A outra pergunta é: Existe algum tempo limite razoável ou recomendado para que eu possa manter boa performance do meu servidor?

**Nota**: Quando estou falando de definir `0`, estou falando da função chamada `set_time_limit`, usada por muitos programadores PHP para aumentar o tempo limite da execuçãod e um script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Se eu definir o tempo limite como 0 para tornar esse tempo de espera infinito, poderia ocasionar perda de performance no meu servidor?**

Independente do cenário, acho que o `set_time_limit(0)` não é uma boa prática. Isso que se o seu sistema der algum bug, o script vai ficar executando e isso vai "acabar" com memória. Ou seja, vai ferir o princípio da eficiência, definido pela [ISO 9241](http://www.userfocus.co.uk/resources/iso9241/intro.html).

**Existe algum tempo limite razoável ou recomendado para que eu possa manter boa performance do meu servidor?**

Na parte de [contribuição da Documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#84563) fala que seu servidor web pode pegar você com um tempo limite imposto HTTP (normalmente cerca de 5 minutos). Você deve verificar os guias do servidor web para obter mais informações sobre tempos limite HTTP.

Answer (score 3):

Pode comprometer a performance sim.

Definir o limite de execução como ZERO, pode causar lentidões ou até mesmo travar o seu servidor.

Veja o tempo máximo necessário, então defina uma margem de folga.

Existe algum tempo limite razoável ou recomendado para que eu possa manter boa performance do meu servidor? Não há uma regra para isso, depende do seu ambiente, recursos do seu servidor, sistema, clientes, uso, etc.

Veja a sua necessidade de tempo e estabeleça uma folga. Mas não recomendo que deixe SEM LIMITE.